# Xcode 8.0 beta No such module found Alamofire Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

Hello Im on Xcode 8 beta and Alamofire is not working. When I do the import statement it says no such module and Im not able to use it. I followed the instructions on Github for installing for Swift 3.0 but it's not working.

Comment: Did you see this link? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1316

Comment: same issue for another framework

Comment: How did you import the framework? Manually? Or pods?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are opening `.xcworkspace` and not `.xcodeproj` file.

Also under : Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries Make sure your frameworks are there.

Answer (score 0):

Command+B (Build the project). The error will be removed